# VBA codes for Excel- Find a cells value in another workbook and copy adjacent cell to the first workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a quick question; I have two workbooks, let's say wbk1 and wbk2; What I am trying to do is finding each cell value of a column in wbk1 in a specific column of wbk2 and return offset cell value from wbk2 to adjacent cell of the searched value in wbk1.

Is there any one who can help?
By the way, I could find following code if it helps;
'=================

```
Sub find1()

Dim Key
Dim Target
Dim Hnum
Dim Success
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim one As Long

Success = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

strSecondFile = "C:\Soroush\08- Technical\03- Stock\Test\PL_Test_01\PL_Test_01.xlsm"
strFrthFile = "C:\Soroush\08- Technical\03- Stock\CNC_Test.xlsx"
'==

 Sheets("sheet2").Select

    Lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(5, 9).Value) Then
    Key = Cells(5, 9).Value

 For i = 5 To Lastrow

' If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 9).Value) Then
'    Key = Cells(i, 9).Value

 Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(strFrthFile)
 With wbk.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set Target = Columns(1).find(Key, LookIn:=xlValues)

    If Not Target Is Nothing Then

        ActiveCell.Select
        Selection.Copy


        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(strSecondFile)
            With wbk.Sheets("Sheet2")
                Sheets("Sheet2").Select
                    Cells(i, 10).Select
                        ActiveCell.Paste


                 If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i + 1, 9).Value) Then
                    Key = Cells(i + 1, 9).Value

            End If

        End With

    End If

 End With
'End If

 Next
    End If

End Sub


'=========================================================================
```

But It does not work and I can't figure it out. I appreciate any comments on this macro.

Cheers

Comment: The `vlookup` formula is the answer here. You can certainly use vlookup in VBA too, but there's probably no need. Spend a little time getting familiar with it in formula form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use INDEX and MATCH.

[image]

In this case, the value in cell E2 is matched against values in B2 to B6. This is then indexed against column C and the value in column C is returned.

*ignore the typo for "mammal"!

Comment: I need a macro! It is another workbook which goes to a worksheet in another workbook and do the job! It will be something similar to the code that I have posted.